# testing different learning methods in scikit learn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Can someone walk me through how to test a few different machine learning methods in sklearn, once I have it working with svm.SVC?

I have:

r = numpy array of 6 features, i.e. shape ~10000 x 6

answer = binary numpy array (1 or 0) that I want to learn to predict, shape ~1000 x 1

I do cross validation:

```
[datatrain, datatest, answertrain, answertest] = cross_validation.train_test_split(r,answer)
```

this works great:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf').fit(datatrain,answertrain) 
prediction = clf.predict(datatest)
```

I want to try linear_model.ElasticNet and ensemble.RandomForestClassifier. (I'm also open to suggestions for methods available in sklearn, as I'm relatively new to machine learning.)

I tried:

```
clf = linear_model.ElasticNet.fit(X=datatrain,y=answertrain)
```

and

```
clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit(X=datatrain,y=answertrain)
```

In both cases I get the error:

```
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try:
`clf = linear_model.ElasticNet()`, then
`clf.fit(datatrain, answertrain)`

Comment: yup, that was it. Any chance you can tell me how to get a ROC here? I can't find an example

Comment: ^^for posterity this is the answer to the error TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf=RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
clf.predict(X_test)
```